# independence of random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation

Suppose we have $2$ Independent random variables $X$ AND $Y$. Let $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ are functions of those $2$ random variables.

1.) my question can we say that the functions $g(X)$ AND $f(Y)$ are independent as well?

2.) and what would be $\mathbb{E}[g(X)f(Y)]$ ?

The problem is that i m having that i m not sure whether $g(X)$ AND $f(Y)$ are independent if $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: The random variables $g(X)$ and $f(Y)$  *are* independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two random variables are indipendent.

Intuitively if x doesn't influence the value of y, so the image of x under f doesn't influence the other variable.

If the two variables are independent then E[g(X)*f(Y)] = E[g(X)]*E[f(X)] which is essentially the fubini theorem (remember the the definition of expectation).